# Grabbing data between two commas

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am in the process of writing a simple script to grab battery information from `acpi` so I can format and output it.

Currently, I am using `cut` to grab this information, but as the battery state changes, `cut` does not grab the correct data and instead will grab a portion of a string instead of the battery percentage.

When running `acpi -b`, I get the following output:

```
Battery 0: Unknown, 100
```

Occasionally, `acpi -b` will also return the following, or something similar if it is charging or discharging:

```
Battery 0: Discharging, 98%, 02:14:14 remaining
```

So, without using `cut`, I'd like to be able to grab the data after the first comma, and, on occasion when present, grab the information between both commas. Right now, I am using sed to strip whitespace and the percentage sign from the output. Here is that command:

```
acpi -b | cut -c20-24 | sed 's/ //g;s/%//g'
```

Comment: Instead of counting characters; count fields: `cut -d, -f2`. This will accommodate a variable size string preceding the percentage.

Comment: echo -e "Battery 0: Unknown, 100\nBattery 0: Discharging, 98%, 02:14:14 remaining"  | sed "s/[[:blank:]]*//g"|cut -d',' -f2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use this simple awk command:

```
s='Battery 0: Unknown, 100'
awk -F',[[:blank:]]*' '{sub(/%/, "", $2); print $2}' <<< "$s"
100

s='Battery 0: Discharging, 98%, 02:14:14 remaining'
awk -F',[[:blank:]]*' '{sub(/%/, "", $2); print $2}' <<< "$s"
98
```

**awk breakup:**

```
-F,[[:blank:]]*   # makes comma followed by 0 or more spaces as field separator
sub(/%/, "", $2)  # remove trailing %
print $2          # print 2nd field
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well, but I am not all too familiar with awk so I used the cut recommendation shown above.

Comment: I based my answer on your requirement **So without using cut I'd like to be able to grab the data after the first comma** Besides `cut` will leave a leading space before number in output which awk takes care of in my command.

Comment: Could you explain how awk handles this? I understand how this works in sed, as I have a piped command within a script that does all this then saves the output as a variable, but im not sure how awk handles removing spaces, or the percentage sign.

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again! This'll help me better incorporate awk into my daily scripting.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
$ str1='Battery 0: Unknown, 100'
$ str2='Battery 0: Discharging, 98%, 02:14:14 remaining'
$ sed 's/^[^,]*, \([0-9]*\).*$/\1/' <<< "$str1"
100
$ sed 's/^[^,]*, \([0-9]*\).*$/\1/' <<< "$str2"
98
```

The substitution matches everything up to the first comma and a space (`^[^,]*,`), then captures any sequence of numbers (`\([0-9]*\)`) and matches the rest of the line (`.*$`), then substitutes the whole line with the captured numbers.